# Utilizing an Azure Pipeline to build Zapier app

Tags: azure-pipelines, zapier-cli

I am attempting to create a build for a Zapier app. I have several npm steps to install and run various checks within Node. I then do an npm global install for the `zapier-platform-cli` package and use a command script to run `zapier validate`. Locally I have this package installed globally and can run this script without issue. However the build will install the package and then when it hits the command task to run `zapier validate` it states zapier is not a batch file or executable and it cannot execute.

I have tried several different methods to get this to run and have been unsuccessful. The build is running on a private build server and not Visual Studio shared. Has anyone been able to get this command to run properly within an Azure pipeline/build?

Build pipeline:

[image]

Error received during build:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the "**`npm install -g zapier-platform-cli`**" task to the top as the first step of the job. Then check if the issue can be resolved.

I have tried this and it can work well as expected.

**[UPDATE]**

You also can try to manually execute the "**`npm install -g zapier-platform-cli`**" command on your local machine to install the **zapier-platform-cli**, then manually execute the **`zapier`** command for your project on the local machine to check whether it can work.

1. If it works locally, try to set up a [**Self-hosted Windows agent**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on the local machine to run the pipeline job.
2. If it also does not work locally, the problem may be laying on the **zapier-platform-cli** itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I attempted this solution and received the same error. Order does not appear to matter in terms of how far in advance the global install occurs.

Comment: Hi @BrandonParker, I have updated my answer with more suggestions. Please check it.

Comment: Hi @BrandonParker, I have not heard from you for a long time. Just want to say hi and whether you have received my previous reply?
As suggested in my previous reply, you can try to manually execute the "npm install -g zapier-platform-cli" command on your local machine to install the zapier-platform-cli, then manually execute the zapier command for your project on the local machine to check whether it can work.

Comment: Hi @BrandonParker I was able to get access to the zapier module by running this script in the YAML. - script: |
    npm install -g zapier-platform-cli
  displayName: 'Zapier CLI install'